# Issue updating infowindow Carto

Tags: ionic2, infowindow, cartodb

I have a problem with the infowindow of one of my sublayers in a Carto map. First of all I'll show my code. I create the layer options and then I get my sublayer. I set its options and a first version of the infowindow. After that, I create the event onclick, what changes the infowindow based on a variable I've declared before.

```
var subLayerOptions2 = {
          sql: "SELECT * FROM zonas WHERE cartodb_id IN (SELECT zonaid FROM devices_zonas WHERE deviceid IN (SELECT deviceid FROM users_devices WHERE userid=" + this.auth.getUserId() + "))",
          cartocss: "#layer {polygon-fill: " + ConstantesColores.colores[3] + "; polygon-opacity: 0.25; line-color: " + ConstantesColores.colores[3] + "; line-width: 1; line-opacity: 1;}",
          interactivity: ['cartodb_id']
}

// Creacion e introduccion del layer en el mapa
var sublayer2 = layer.getSubLayer(2);
sublayer2.set(subLayerOptions2);
sublayer2.infowindow.set('template', infow);
sublayer2.on('featureClick', (e, latlng, pos, data, layer) => {
              sublayer2.infowindow.set('template', infow.replace("#DispAsociados#", arrayZonasConDisp[data.cartodb_id].info));
              alert("Hey! You clicked " + data.cartodb_id);
});
sublayers.push(sublayer2);
```

The problem is that, the first time I click an element of the map, the infowindow is not updating well, the variable is empty, but when I click a second time it appears well. If I change the element I click, the first time appears the info corresponding to the last click, not this one. It's like a delay. It always show the info of the previous one.

Does anyone know why this happens?

Comment: I have already answered this same question in GIS SE: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/243441/problem-updating-infowindow

Comment: Yes! In that link is the solution!